# What is the simplest way of uploading images in Nodejs / Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a form through which user can upload an image. I want to upload it by the nodejs, save in DB (mongodb) and display back to template(EJS).

I read about gridFS, but I am looking for simplest way of just UPLOADING THE IMAGE.

EJS:

```
<h2>Enter your Data</h2>
<form action="/test" method="POST">
<input type="username" placeholder="username" name="Username" /> <br />
<input type="text" placeholder="title" name="Name" /><br />
<textarea name="Description" ></textarea><br />
<input type="link" name="Clink"/><br />
<input type="file" name="imgUpload"/><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btn"/>
</form>



var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var fs = require('fs');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var about = require('./routes/about');
//var contact = require('./routes/contact');
//var blogData = require('./routes/blogData');

var app = express();


//Connect DB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/dataTest');

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/about', about);
//app.use('/contact', contact);
//app.use('/blogData', blogData);

//Scheme
var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id : String,
    Name   : String,
    Description    : String,
    Clink : String
});

//Model
var BlogPost = mongoose.model('Blog', Schema);

app.post('/test',function(req,res){
  new BlogPost({
      _id : req.body.Username,
      Name : req.body.Name,
      Description : req.body.Description,
      Clink : req.body.Clink
  }).save(function(err, doc){
    if(err){
      console.log('boo');
    }
    else{
      console.log('inner');
      res.redirect('contact');
      res.end();
      }
  })
});
```

Comment: https://github.com/expressjs/multer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To upload the image in node.js you can simply use **base64** encoding,and insert into MongoDb.

And while retrieving you can fetch **base64** encoded image and convert it into image format.

```
<input type="file" id="fileinput" name ="image" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
```

First convert your image to base64 and save into Database:

```
router.post('/upload',function(req,res){
var base64ToBuffer = new Buffer(req.image, 'base64');//Convert to base64

//Write your insertcode of MongoDb

res.end("Image uploaded Successfully"); 
});
```

After that to display image you can write another router:

```
router.get('/showImage', function(req, res) {
    // Write code to retrieve image base64 code
    var imageBase64;
    render image to jade template
})
```

Comment: Thank, but how I can render the image in EJS template? By just using the imageBase64 variable? We don't need to store it in DB?

Comment: Actully,i dont have EJS template knowledge,but you can change your EJS template engine to HTML so you can use HTML as a Front end.

Comment: Try this Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963743/display-dynamically-an-image-using-express-and-ejs