# How do I display a user-uploaded image with Express and EJS?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Basically what the title says. Here's what I have got:

I read the images from a form using [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer), which I set up like this:

```
var multer = require('multer');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var router = express.Router();

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, callback){
    callback(null, './imgs/')
 },
 filename: function(req, file, callback) {
     callback(null, "tmp" + path.extname(file.originalname));
 }
});

router.route('/items/item-create/:cat_id')
.post(upload.single('img'), itemController.postItem);
```

This works as intended, so I'll not provide the code for itemController.postItem.

I saved the images in a folder called "imgs", which I have made static, like so:

```
var app = express();    
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'imgs')));
```

The images each correspond to a mongoDB document(called "item"), so they are named as "item._id.jpg". I wrote a basic ejs template("item.ejs") which accepts the item document and uses its _id to generate the filename and use it in an "img" tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><%=it.name%></p>
        <img src="<%= it._id.toString() + '.jpg' %>" alt="image">       
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the function which renders the template, invoked on a GET request to /items/:item_id :

```
exports.getItem = function(req, res){
    Item.findOne({ _id:req.params.item_id }, function(err, item){
        if(err) res.send(err);
        console.log("In getItem...");
        console.log(req.params.item_id);        
        console.log(item);              
        res.render('item', { it: item });
        
    });
};
```

It shows the item name correctly, but it refuses to load the image, and somehow the program sends another GET request to the same url, but with the image name as the :item_id parameter, which obviously throws an error about being unable to read property "name" of "undefined". What am I doing wrong here?

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963743/display-dynamically-an-image-using-express-and-ejs), but it threw an 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, turns out I had mounted the static folder incorrectly. As I needed the images at /items/ (and also at /categories/:cat_id/cat-details, which I did not mention in my question), I mounted it as follows:

```
app.use(['/items/', '/categories/:cat_id/details/'], express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'imgs')));
```